# Godot/Gdscript: Why is str2var not working on classes with _init method?

Tags: serialization, godot, gdscript

Let's define 2 classes

A.gd

```
class_name A

var v = null

func _init(v_):
    v = v_
```

B.gd

```
class_name B

var v = null
```

Now, when I try to use str2var/var2str, this is what I get

```
var a = A.new("aaa")
var b = B.new()
b.v = "bbb"

printt("var2str(a):", var2str(a))
printt("var2str(b):", var2str(b))

printt ("var2str(str2var(var2str(a))):", var2str(str2var(var2str(a))))
printt ("var2str(str2var(var2str(b))):", var2str(str2var(var2str(b))))
```

**Output**:

```
var2str(a): Object(Reference,"script":Resource( "res://Scripts/AI/A.gd"),"v":"aaa")

var2str(b): Object(Reference,"script":Resource( "res://Scripts/AI/B.gd"),"v":"bbb")

var2str(str2var(var2str(a))):   Object(Reference,"script":null)

var2str(str2var(var2str(b))):   Object(Reference,"script":Resource( "res://Scripts/AI/B.gd"),"v":"bbb")
```

Why is str2var(a) not working?

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Solution

Fix it by making the parameter optional, for example:

```
class_name A

var v = null

func _init(v_ = null):
    v = v_
```

With that there is no error. I get this output:

```
var2str(a): Object(Reference,"script":Resource( "res://A.gd"),"v":"aaa")

var2str(b): Object(Reference,"script":Resource( "res://B.gd"),"v":"bbb")

var2str(str2var(var2str(a))):   Object(Reference,"script":Resource( "res://A.gd"),"v":"aaa")

var2str(str2var(var2str(b))):   Object(Reference,"script":Resource( "res://B.gd"),"v":"bbb")
```

---

### The problem

For abstract, `str2var` will not pass any arguments to `_init`. *It would not know what to pass anyway.*

*The rest of the answer is the process of confirming that `str2var` will result in calling `_init` with no argument.*

---

When I try your code I get this error:

```
E 0:00:00.630   _create_instance: Condition "r_error.error != Variant::CallError::CALL_OK" is true. Returned: __null
  <C++ Source>  modules/gdscript/gdscript.cpp:121 @ _create_instance()
  <Stack Trace> main.gd:12 @ _ready()
```

We can find the line that throws the error in `_create_instance` by looking at the [source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/modules/gdscript/gdscript.cpp#L121).

Sadly that does not give me much information. So, I decided to search how `str2var` is implemented.

We find it inside `GDScriptFunctions::call`, [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/modules/gdscript/gdscript_functions.cpp#L826). Which calls [`VariantParser::parse`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/core/variant_parser.cpp#L1512), which calls [`VariantParser::parse_value`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/core/variant_parser.cpp#L487). We are interested in the case of an `"Object"` ([here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/core/variant_parser.cpp#L691)). And that results in a call to `ClassDB::instance(type)`. There type will be `"Reference"`, and then it procedes to set all properties as they come. Being the first one `"script":Resource("res://A.gd")`.

When we set the script ([here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/core/object.cpp#L1011)), it will result in a call to [`GDScript::instance_create`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/modules/gdscript/gdscript.cpp#L307). Which calls `GDScript::_create_instance` ([here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/modules/gdscript/gdscript.cpp#L324)):

```
return _create_instance(NULL, 0, p_this, Object::cast_to<Reference>(p_this) != NULL, unchecked_error)
```

With no argument for `_init` (The `NULL` is the argument array, and `0` is the number of arguments). This is the signature for [`GDScript::_create_instance`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/modules/gdscript/gdscript.cpp#L85):

```
GDScriptInstance *GDScript::_create_instance(const Variant **p_args, int p_argcount, Object *p_owner, bool p_isref, Variant::CallError &r_error)
```

Of course, `initializer->call(instance, p_args, p_argcount, r_error);` fails, because `_init` requires an argument. And we find the line that throws the error further down. *Note: `initializer` is created while parsing the script.*

Comment: Impressive answer, as always.